# SQL LIKE only works on first word

Tags: sql, wildcard, cpu-word, sql-like, words

I'm trying to use LIKE to find a string that has multiple words however the results I get only include matches on the first word. For example, using this query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM shouts WHERE shout LIKE '%$search%' ";
```

If I search for "k" I only get results that have a "k" in the first word but no results with a "k" in any other words. I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please share some sample data and the result you expect to get for this sample?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Note, you should never apply variables direct to queries as it leaves the query open to SQL injection attacks

Comment: Why are you using $ inside string?Which dbms you are using?

Comment: How do I apply the variable to the query so that it is not open to injection attacks?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I solved the problem and posted the answer. I'm using MySQL in php.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong about this. I was fooled to think multiple words were in the database when in fact the extra words were added to the results after the query so that's why my query couldn't find them. I've added other sentences with multiple words and the LIKE operator worked fine on them.